# How to remove header in PDF export result from DataTable and change color table fill to white?

Tags: laravel, datatables

I tried removing the header in the exported PDF from the DataTable but it didn't work. Also, how to change the color table to full white and border black?

```
var table = $('#ReportTable').DataTable( {
    lengthChange: false,
    buttons: [
                {"extend": 'pdf', 
                "className": 'btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-pill px-3 mb-3 mb-sm-0',
                    customize: function(doc) {
                        doc.header = false;
                        doc.pageMargins = [ 150, 20, 150, 20 ];
                    },
                },
                {
                    "extend": 'print',
                    "className": 'btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-pill px-3 mb-3 mb-sm-0'
                },
            ]
} );

table.buttons().container()
    .appendTo( '#ReportTable_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)' );
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `title` to control the title ("SiPanda") and you can use `customize` to control the different colors (striped lines) used for alternate rows in the PDF.

I don't want to interfere with your existing use of `customize`, so here is my test example which you can use as a model:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
dom: 'Brftip',
buttons: [
  { 
    extend: 'pdfHtml5', 
    text: 'To PDF',
    title: '',
    customize: function ( pdf, btn, tbl ) {
      delete pdf.styles.tableBodyOdd.fillColor;
    }
  }  
]
} );
```

The `title: ''` is straightforward (assuming your PDF is actually getting its title from the web page's title).

The `delete pdf.styles.tableBodyOdd.fillColor;` assumes that your DataTable is using the "standard" zebra-stripes" style.

This command works because the DataTable passes the following properties to PDFMake:

```js
tableBodyEven: Object {  }
tableBodyOdd: Object { fillColor: "#f3f3f3" }
```

So, we remove the `fillColor: "#f3f3f3"` property from the `tableBodyOdd` object.

If you have used a different DataTables styling, you may see something different from what I see - in which case you can use `console.log( pdf );` to take a closer look.

---

**UPDATE**

I missed the part about "*and border black*" - so here is an approach for that, also:

```js
buttons: [
  { 
    extend: 'pdfHtml5', 
    text: 'To PDF',
    title: '',
    customize: function ( pdf, btn, tbl ) {
      delete pdf.styles.tableBodyOdd.fillColor;

      pdfMake.tableLayouts = {
        exampleLayout: {
          hLineWidth: function (i) {
            return 0.2;
          },
          vLineWidth: function (i) {
            return 0.2;
          },
          hLineColor: function (i) {
            return 'black';
          },
          vLineColor: function (i) {
            return 'black';
          }
          //paddingLeft: function (i) {
          //  return i === 0 ? 0 : 8;
          //},
          //paddingRight: function (i, node) {
          //  return (i === node.table.widths.length - 1) ? 0 : 8;
          //}
        }
      };

      pdf.content[0].layout = "exampleLayout";
    }
  }  
]
```

In the above snippet, I define an object called `pdfMake.tableLayouts` which contains a custom object called `exampleLayout`.

My `exampleLayout` defines thin black lines around every cell in the table.

I then use this custom layout by using:

```
pdf.content[0].layout = "exampleLayout";
```

You can choose your own line widths and colors.

---

The end result:

[image]